# Zabbix ldap url support

Tags: ldap, zabbix

Does Zabbix support accessing ldap:hostname/... checks? I attempted to set up an item using HTTP check to check the following:

```
ldap://{HOST.IP}/principalName=username,cn=Users,SECAUTHORITY=DEFAULT?dn??(&(secAcctValid=TRUE)(secPwdValid=TRUE))
```

But it returns an error `header is empty`, which suggests to me it may be appending http before the url, or ignoring the ldap://?
I can use the web check for the same functionality (and it does work with the required string for what I am expecting to be returned), which I suppose would fit my needs, but it would be nice to be able to view the output for some of the other ldap checks we are currently using. Alternatively, is it possible to set up just a standard curl request instead? I saw the system.run[command] option, but I'm not sure how to escape the commas in the url.

Manual curl command (different username in usage)
`curl -s --user user:pass ldap://IP-ADDRESS/principalName=username,cn=Users,SECAUTHORITY=DEFAULT`

Output from curl is this(some values are removed)
`DN: principalName=username,cn=Users,secAuthority=Default
        objectclass: 
        objectclass: 
        objectclass: 
        objectclass:

```
    secLoginType: Default:LDAP

    principalName: 

    secUUID: 

    secDomainId: 

    secDN: 

    secHasPolicy: true

    secAuthority: Default:

    secPwdFailCountTime: 20160426150110.0Z

    secPwdLastChanged: 20180924201506.0Z

    secPwdValid: TRUE

    secAcctValid: TRUE`
```

Comment: Please provide the error message. Furthermore it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I included the error, there is a red warning and the pop-up text states 
`header is empty`
I'm trying to pull the ldap entry, so 
`DN: principalName=username,cn=Users,secAuthority=Default
objectclass: ...`
but instead it returns no data. 
from command line I am hoping for an output similar to what this would return:
`curl -s --user user:pass ldap://IP-ADDRESS/principalName=username,cn=Users,SECAUTHORITY=DEFAULT`

Comment: Of course if you use and http check it expects an http header, which obviously an ldap server won't provide. You should use a net.tcp.service check instead.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by https://superuser.com/users/2914/wazoox HTTP check is for HTTP protocol. It will not work with `ldap://` URL .

I advise you to setup UserParameter Item that will check for your LDAP query via `curl` as you did and return the value to zabbix server for further evaluation.

UserParameter docs: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/manual/config/items/userparameters